# How to modify bigcommerce frontend with api (add js code in app)

Tags: javascript, addition, bigcommerce

I am writing and app for biggommerce which should a bit of code JS to the header. Does bigcommerce allow to do something like that? (something like ScriptTag in Shopify)

Best Regards
Vahe Abelyan

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access/edit template files thru the Bigcommerce API. It would just be best to guide the user to pasting the JS into their header (as most apps already do).

Answer (score 0):

Rob is correct, however, depending on how complex you want to get you could technically write an app that would fetch or put a file into the theme's template structure using WebDAV.

Basically
if /template/panels/htmlhead.html exists find it, add your script code before , then post file back to webdav

if /template/panels/htmlhead.html does not exist, allow user to upload the default one from their theme, and then have you app do the same thing.

However I'd recommend sticking with the easy way, just provide instructions for a user to place the code into the file themselves. If you want a great example of this, see YOTPO's installation instructions.

Comment: How can we do this using WebDAV? for that, the app must need a permission to the themes - Do you mean by asking oauth permission on themes in app's "technical" tab?

Comment: If you're using the new Stencil theme system this approach will not work